# Appium Did not successfully proxy server command

Tags: automation, appium, bluestacks

I have:

[test_instagram.rb]

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'
appium_txt = 'E:\\Instagram\\appium.txt'
caps = Appium.load_appium_txt file: appium_txt, verbose: false
Appium::Driver.new(caps).start_driver
driver_quit
```

[appium.txt]

```
[caps]
platformName = "android"
app = "E:\\Instagram\\instagram.apk"
deviceName = "emulator-5554"
automationName = "Selendroid"
```

I have started the server with this command: `node . --no-reset --session-override`

when i run `ruby test_instagram.rb`, the app starts in emulator (bluestack) and then the following error happens:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': Did not successfully proxy server command (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/appium_lib-4.0.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:436:in `start_driver'
        from test_instagram.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

what is the problem and How to fix?